# fullcalendar - recurring events

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, fullcalendar

I as wondering if anyone could help me with a problem? I am using fullcalendar and it works great, but I would like to add the ability to repeat events upon user requests (by the way i'm using the selectable calendar). In other words I want to give them an option to recure the events based off whatever they choose (weekly, daily, monthly, unorganized days). I have read the docs and I know that recurring events are based off of the id and you basically add the days to the original date, but I am not sure how to do it without making a loop adding multiple events that may or may not be necessary.

My thought was to provide a column in mysql that gives a recurring option based off of the selection. Any ideas on how I should approach this. Does anyone possibly have an example that I can brainstorm on? All help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I had  a similar issue- In the end I made an entry in the database for each event.. it is easier to group it with SQL select and also will naturally come back- but maintaining  the recurrent can be problematic.

Comment: It's a good idea, but I'm not sure this i what I am looking for. That seems like it could eventually be very inefficient, but it may be what I have to do if I can't figure this out. I'm thinking if I can add a column to the table that is a final recurrence date then I can mathematically figure the amount of recurrences and loop through the row that many times. The problem I am having trouble with now is, how to separate the type of occurrence.

Comment: So I know I'm late to the party here, but I'll post a comment for future googlers. I recently made a post on how I use fullcalendar with recurring events. http://www.fajitanachos.com/web-development/fullcalendar-and-recurring-events/

Comment: just checked it out, very nice +1

Comment: @FajitaNachos if you post that in the answer board, i'll mark it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I did to implement recurring events in fullcalendar.

http://fajitanachos.com/Fullcalendar-and-recurring-events/

I did end up using a loop to add events to my events table based on the recurring frequency. I know it's not the most efficient but it works for my purposes.

One thing to consider is how much flexibility do you need? Do you need an event to repeat every Tuesday/Thursday, every 3rd Saturday, the last day of the month, or simply every week on a certain day? The more flexibility you need, the more complex your solution will need to be.

Answer (score 3):

It's nothing to do with fullcalendar. You need to have this implemented in your back-end. I wouldn't recommend you creating a column in your events table in order to maintain recurring once you might need a recurring type (weekly, daily, monthly, yearly) or frequency for example.
I've faced this same type of solution few months ago and I would recommend you create another table called tb_events_recurring, for example, saving information like event_id, date_start, date_end and recurring type if necessary. 
Create an event for each recurring are hard stuff to maintain. My advise is creating this events every time fullcalendar request them. You have the date_start and date_end in your post vars, so it won't be cost for your server. Put all events in an array and after encode 'em to json.

Comment: Do you have a working example by chance? I have played around with a few ideas with no luck on anything. My newest thought is to create a recurrence frequency, to the server, and then when i read out from the array, recure them client side based off the value in the recurrence field. I like your idea, but could you elaborate on implementation. thanks

Comment: Im straight coding using php 5.2.something, jquery, json, ajax, mysql